# Error: cannot load such file -- mysqltopostgres (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have installed mysqltopostgres in linux. when trying to run `mysqltopostgres` I am getting this error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysqltopostgres-0.3.0/bin/mysqltopostgres:7:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysqltopostgres (LoadError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysqltopostgres-0.3.0/bin/mysqltopostgres:7:in `<top (required)>'
```

Could not find proper answer about how to deal with this. Would appreciate your help there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
mysqldump --compatible=postgresql yourdatabase >dump.sql
```

Comment: @osherdo let me know if this helped you or not

Comment: I am checking it now (having 1045 error in mysql, so I am fixing it right now). WIll post here what's the output for this solution. Thanks!

Comment: I am now trying to upload it to heroku as a postgres sql file. that's what you expected me to do right? doing it now.

Comment: I don't think that's gonna with with heroku. They want the file to be passed in this format: `PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump`